# Too many values inside a Where

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to get all products inside an order. I give to my procedure the ID of the order and then I want to list all of them.
Here is the database scheme of the tables I use in this procedure:

[image: Database schema]

And here is the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE exercitiu6(v_ID_Comanda Comanda.ID_Comanda%TYPE) AS
    TYPE produse IS TABLE OF Produs%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    p produse;
    TYPE imbricat IS TABLE OF ProduseComanda.ID_Produs%TYPE;
    imbricat_produse imbricat:= imbricat();
    prod Produs%ROWTYPE;
    i number:=0;
    j number:=0;
 BEGIN 
    SELECT ID_Produs BULK COLLECT INTO imbricat_produse FROM ProduseComanda
    WHERE ID_Comanda = v_ID_Comanda;
    FOR i IN imbricat_produse.FIRST..imbricat_produse.LAST LOOP
        SELECT ID_Produs, nume, pret INTO prod FROM Produs
        WHERE ID_Produs = imbricat_produse(i);
        p(j):= prod;
        j:= j + 1; 
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Comanda cu ID-ul ' || v_ID_Comanda || ' contine urmatoarele produse: ');
    FOR j IN p.FIRST..p.LAST LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p(j).nume);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I get the Error Sql Statement ignored; too many values on this line:

```
WHERE ID_Comanda = v_ID_Comanda;
```

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `JOIN` and a single cursor:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE exercitiu6(
  v_ID_Comanda ProduseComanda.ID_Comanda%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN 
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Comanda cu ID-ul ' || v_ID_Comanda || ' contine urmatoarele produse: ');

   FOR i IN (
     SELECT p.nume
     FROM   ProduseComanda c
            INNER JOIN Produs p
            ON p.ID_Produs = c.ID_Produs
     WHERE  c.ID_Comanda = v_ID_Comanda
   )
   LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.nume);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE produsecomanda (ID_Produs, ID_Comanda) AS
  SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE produs (ID_Produs, nume) AS
  SELECT 1, 'Alice' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Beryl' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Carol' FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE();
  exercitiu6(1);
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> Comanda cu ID-ul 1 contine urmatoarele produse: 
> Alice
> Beryl
> Carol
> ```

---

If you want to fix your code then the error is not with the `WHERE` clause but with the mismatch between the number of columns in the `SELECT` clause and the `INTO` clause. To fix it you need to use `SELECT * INTO ...` rather than naming all the columns when you are working with `%ROWTYPE` variables:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE exercitiu6(
  v_ID_Comanda ProduseComanda.ID_Comanda%TYPE
)
AS
    TYPE produse IS TABLE OF Produs%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    p produse;
    TYPE imbricat IS TABLE OF ProduseComanda.ID_Produs%TYPE;
    imbricat_produse imbricat;
    i number:=0;
    j number:=0;
 BEGIN 
    SELECT ID_Produs
    BULK COLLECT INTO imbricat_produse
    FROM   ProduseComanda
    WHERE  ID_Comanda = v_ID_Comanda;

    FOR i IN imbricat_produse.FIRST..imbricat_produse.LAST LOOP
        j:= j + 1;
        SELECT *
        INTO   p(j)
        FROM   Produs
        WHERE  ID_Produs = imbricat_produse(i);
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Comanda cu ID-ul ' || v_ID_Comanda || ' contine urmatoarele produse: ');
    FOR j IN p.FIRST..p.LAST LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p(j).nume);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-zTidm9N)

Comment: I must use 2 collection types for a college project. I think I know what Is happening in my code but I can't find a way to solve it. The Select clause where I have the problem returns duplicates of the same ID_Produs. I have the ID_Produs 1,2,3,4,5 two times each.

Comment: @Eclipsa Updated - Use `SELECT * INTO ...` rather than naming columns when you are working with `%ROWTYPE`s.